# Modificar variables globales

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estaba haciendo un programa muy simple que consiste en que el usuario escoge un número entre el uno al cien y la computadora intenta adivinarlo.

Si la computadora no adivina, tu debes decirle si el número que escogió es un número más alto o más bajo que el tuyo y de esta manera la computadora modifica los valores del `randint`.

El problema es que, por ejemplo, cuando la computadora no adivina y tu escribes "mas bajo" no se modifica el valor `mini` (el mínimo entre el uno y el cien para buscar un número). Ya me di cuenta que es lo que pasó: Cuando quiero modificar los valores `mini` y `maxi` el intérprete los toma como valores locales y no modifica los valores globales.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los valores se modifiquen?.

Aquí tienen el código:

```
import random
print("Te voy a explicar las reglas del juego: Tu escojes un número del 1  al 100. La computadora intenta adivinar tu número. Si tu por ejemplo escojiste el 15 y la computadora escojió el 10 debes decirle: \"más alto\" y si dice 34 debes decirle: \"más bajo\"")

adivina = int(input("Vamos a jugar :D. Elige un número del 1 al 100: "))

def adivinador():
    while True:
        adivinanza = random.randint(mini, maxi)
        print("Es:" + " " + str(adivinanza) + " " + "el número que has escogido?")
        respuesta = input("Si/No: ")
        intentos = 0
        mini = 1
        maxi = 100        
        print(mini)
        print(maxi)
        print(adivinanza)
        if respuesta == "Si":
            print("Bieeeen he ganado :D" + " " + "y en solo" + " " + str(intentos) + " " + "intentos")
            break
        elif respuesta == "No":
            print("Mi número es más bajo o más alto que el tuyo?")
            min_max = input("mas bajo/ mas alto: ")
            if min_max == "mas bajo":
                mini = adivinanza
                intentos += 1
            elif min_max == "más alto":
                maxi = adivinanza
                intentos += 1
            else:
                print("Estoy confundido.")

adivinador()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas usar variables globales. No es un problema de ámbito, lo que pasa es que simplemente en cada iteración del `while` vuelves a reiniciar los valores de `mini`, `maxi` e `intentos`. Lo único que tienes que hacer es sacarlos del `while`, pero seguirán siendo variables locales propias de la función y que solo esa función podrá acceder y modificar:

```
def adivinador():
    intentos = 0
    mini = 1
    maxi = 100   
    while True:
        adivinanza = random.randint(mini, maxi)
        print("Es:" + " " + str(adivinanza) + " " + "el número que has escogido?")
        respuesta = input("Si/No: ")

        if respuesta == "Si":
            print("Bieeeen he ganado :D" + " " + "y en solo" + " " + str(intentos) + " " + "intentos")
            break
        elif respuesta == "No":
            print("Mi número es más bajo o más alto que el tuyo?")
            min_max = input("más bajo/ más alto: ")
            if min_max == "más bajo":
                mini = adivinanza + 1
                intentos += 1
            elif min_max == "más alto":
                maxi = adivinanza - 1
                intentos += 1
            else:
                print("No me ayudas mucho... :(") 
        else:
            print("No me ayudas mucho... :(")
```

Ten cuidado con los `input`, debes ingresar exactamente lo mismo. Tienes "más alto" con tilde pero el `print` del `input` pide "mas alto".

Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que `random.randint` retorna un entero pseudoaleatorio comprendido entre los dos números que se le dan, **incluidos estos**. Para que no quepa la posibilidad se que vuelva a preguntar por el mismo número debes tener esto en cuenta, de forma que restas uno a `maxi` y sumas uno a `mini` cuando los modificas.

---

Ya que  lo mencionas, aunque no es tu problema real, para acceder a una variable global (definida a nivel del módulo) se usa la palabra reservada `global`. Esto solo es necesario para reasignarle un nuevo objeto, no para su lectura o acceso a sus métodos.

```
n = 0
print("Valor de variable n global antes de ejecutar foo: ",  n)

def foo(m):
    global n
    n = n + m
    print("Valor de n dentro de foo: ",  n)
foo(4)
print("Valor de variable n global trás ejecutar foo: ",  n)
```