# Error en import: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Estaba probando el código corregido de esta pregunta: [Modificar variables globales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104147/modificar-variables-globales/104155#104155) . Y cuando intento ejecutarlo en la terminal me lanza un error que dice que el modulo `random` no tiene el atributo `randint` (lo cual no me parece tener ningún sentido):

```
random = random.randint(1,10)
```

> AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'

Por si sirve de algo estoy ejecutándolo en una pc con Ubuntu Gnome con Anaconda instalado.

Comment: ¿No habrás llamado por casualidad a un módulo creado por tí `random.py` y lo has guardado en el directorio de trabajo actual? Y no llames a tu variablee `random`, en la próxima ejecución `random` será un entero y te dirá algo parecido.

Comment: De hecho si tenia un script llamado random :/ mi error. Voy a dejar la pregunta por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es importante **no crear un modulo llamado `random.py` en el mismo directorio donde esta el script** (o en el directorio de trabajo actual en el caso del interprete interactivo) que intenta importar `random.randint` de  la stdlib. En general hay que intentar evitar nombrar nuestros script con nombres que puedan entrar en conflictos con la biblioteca estándar o con otras bibliotecas externas instaladas (como nombrar módulos con la palabra "django" cuando se trabaja con este framework).

Esto tiene que ver en que directorios y en qué orden se resuelven los imports. Cuando se importa un módulo (importe absoluto), por ejemplo usando:

```
>>> import random
```

El intérprete busca ese módulo en las siguientes localizaciones y por este orden:

1. Módulos built-in.
2. El directorio que contiene el script o el directorio actual si no se especifica ningún script (por ejemplo al ejecutar el interprete interactivo en la terminal).
3. Búsqueda en el [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
4. Ruta predeterminada dependiente de la instalación, por ejemplo `/usr/local/lib/python`.

No todos los módulos de la biblioteca estándar son módulos built-in (preconstruidos). Los módulos built-in están escritos en C y son compilados como parte del propio intérprete  Python, por lo tanto no tienen un archivo .py ni los vamos a encontrar por ningún lado. Estos módulos se pueden listar mediante:

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> sys.builtin_module_names
>
> ('_abc',
>  '_ast',
>  '_codecs',
>  '_collections',
>  '_functools',
>  '_imp',
>  '_io',
>  '_locale',
>  '_operator',
>  '_signal',
>  '_sre',
>  '_stat',
>  '_string',
>  '_symtable',
>  '_thread',
>  '_tracemalloc',
>  '_warnings',
>  '_weakref',
>  'atexit',
>  'builtins',
>  'errno',
>  'faulthandler',
>  'gc',
>  'itertools',
>  'marshal',
>  'posix',
>  'pwd',
>  'sys',
>  'time',
>  'xxsubtype')
> ```

¿Entonces que ocurre aquí?. Pues que **`random` no ésta entre los módulos buit-in** aunque sea de la stdlib y como aclara la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> Después de la inicialización, los programas de Python pueden modificar `sys.path`. El directorio que contiene el script que se está ejecutando **se coloca al principio de la ruta de búsqueda, por delante de la ruta de biblioteca estándar**. Esto significa que los scripts de ese directorio se cargarán en lugar de los módulos del mismo nombre de la stdlib. Esto es un error, a menos que el reemplazo esté pensado.

Esto también ocurre cuando se ejecuta un script que está dentro de un paquete, ya que Python no interpretará ese directorio como un paquete, agregando así el directorio de trabajo al `PYTHONPATH` igual que lo comentado antes.

Por lo tanto cualquier directorio o módulo que llamemos igual que a un módulo de la stdlib no built-in o de terceros instalado solapará a éstos. Solo los módulos builtin como sys están a salvo de ésto.

> **Nota**: los módulos buit-in dependen de la instalación, no en todos los casos van a ser los mismos.

---

Observase que tendremos un error muy similar si nuestro script se llama igual que un paquete de terceros instalado que tratamos de importar.

Si por ejemplo tratamos de importar `pandas` con el típico `import pandas as pd` y nuestro script se llama `pandas.py`, el script se  importará a si mismo y no al paquete pandas dado que está antes en el orden como mencionamos arriba.

Si tratamos de usar `from` para importar una clase, función, paquete, etc en específico nos encontramos directamente con un error del tipo:

`pandas.py`

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'DataFrame' from partially initialized
> module 'pandas' (most likely due to a circular import)
> ```

debido al intento de importarse a si mismo del módulo.