# No puedo pasar de una base de datos MySql a json con python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, json, python-2.7

les comento mi problema..
tengo que pasar una tabla de una base de datos (MySql) generada en la cmd y pasarla a un archivo json, el tema es que tengo el scrip y al mostrar dato por dato me funciona pero cuando quiero agregarlo a la lista, es como si no existieran.
base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
aca el scrip:

```
import mysql.connector
import json

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host      = "localhost",
  user      = "root",
  passwd    = "polopo123",
  database  = "universidad"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
universidad = []
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM prueba;")
resultF = cursor.fetchall()
facultades = []
for rowF in resultF:    
    universidad.append({'Piso' : rowF[0], 'Baño' : rowF[1], 'Inicio alerta' : rowF[2], 'Fin alerta' : rowF[3], 'Tiempo de reposicion' : rowF[4]})
json.dumps({universidad})

with open('universidad.json', 'w+') as outfile:
    json.dump(universidad, outfile)
conn.close()
```

este es el problema que me arroja en la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la unica linea que noto que me da problemas es "universidad.append({'Piso' : rowF[0], 'Baño' : rowF[1], 'Inicio alerta' : rowF[2], 'Fin alerta' : rowF[3], 'Tiempo de reposicion' : rowF[4]})", probe todo por separado y solo es esa linea.

Comment: Primero, **nunca jamás llames a un módulo propio con el mismo nombre que uno de la stdlib** (o con el mismo nombre que un paquete de terceros instalado si quieres hacer uso de él). Tu módulo se llama `json.py` igual que el paquete de la stdlib el cual tratas de importar y usar, al hacer eso en vez de importar `json` de la stdlib consigues que tu `json.py` se importe a si mismo...... Cambia el nombre de tu módulo a otra cosa que no solape a un modulo/paquete de la biblioteca estándar.

Comment: El problema "gordo" es el anterior. En cuanto al error final, no veo como es posible que `fetchall` retorne `None`... Si no quedaran filas por retornar `fetchall` retorna una lista vacía nunca `None`.... (otra cosa es `fetchone`...). ¿Ese código exactamente como está se corresponde con ese error?

Comment: Cambia lo del nombre y actualiza el código y el error si sigues con problemas. El primer problema es realmente un posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104174/15089.

Comment: Solucionado, era sólo el error de nombre, muchas gracias.