# TK is not import

Tags: python

Teniendo en cuenta este codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
raiz=tk
raiz.mainloop()
```

Que es lo que hago mal para que vs code me suelte este error:

```
from tkinter import Tk
  File "c:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\python-course\tkinter.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tkinter import Tk
ImportError: cannot import name 'Tk' from 'tkinter' (c:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\python-course\tkinter.py)
```

Teniendo en cuenta que estoy importandolo todo

Comment: Has llamado `tkinter.py` a tu programa? Por eso no encuentra `Tk` dentro de `tkinter`, porque lo busca en tu fichero. Cámbiale el nombre.

Comment: Primero, como comenta abulafia no llames a tus script con el mismo nombre que un paquete de la stdlib o de terceros que tengas instalado, es el mismo problema que el expuesto en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104174/15089. Segundo, no es `tk`, la clase es `Tk` (la mayúscula). Tercero, tienes que instanciar la clase : `raiz = Tk()`. Por otro lado, no importes usando wildcard (es una mala práctica), usa `import tkinter as tk` y `raiz= tk.Tk()`