# error urllib en python 3.7 con windows 10 y sublime text3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de importar el **urllib** y me da este error:

> "import urllib.request ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package"

¿qué puedo hacer?

estoy trabajando en **windows 10** con **python 3.7**

Comment: ¿No se llamará tu script en el que intentas importar  `urllib.py` o tienes alguno en el mismo directorio que se llama así por casualidad?

Comment: ¿Edgar tiene como comentaba arriba tu script el nombre `urllib.py` u otro script en la misma carpeta lo tiene? Si es así simplemente cambia el nombre de ese archivo, no nombres tus script con el mismo nombre que paquetes/módulos de la biblioteca estándar o de terceros instalados que pretendas importar y usar. Si es esto tu problema es el mismo que: [Error en import: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104174/15089). Si no lo es comenta aclarandolo, para que podamos seguir  buscando causas.

Comment: Si ya me di cuenta del error mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo con el comentario de @FJSevilla lo que te está ocurriendo es que tienes un script/fichero, donde se encuentran las librerías de Python llamado urllib, y por tanto no estás importando la librería urllib que es lo que tu quieres, si no este script.

Tienes que sacar este script de la carpeta de librerías de python, para que llame que solo haya un urllib y sea el paquete que quieres importar.

Comment: como se hace eso soy nuevo en esto

Comment: En Windows sería en tú disco donde tengas instalado Python, en archivos del programa, y te vas a Python, donde esté instalado. Una vez dentro de python vas aquí \lib\site-packages. Por ejemplo podría ser algo así: C:\Program Files\python3.7\/lib\site-packages. Ahí te deberían de aparecer dos archivos con el nombre "urllib" uno que es el módulo que tú quieres utilizar, y otro que será un fichero guardado con el mismo nombre