# Hola, me sale este error al intentar leer un excel con python en sublime text

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rutas, sublimetext3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya probe copiando el excel tanto donde tengo instalado el pandas como donde guardo el archivo .py, esto me pasa en el interprete de sublime text con jupyter no tuve problemas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en import: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104174/error-en-import-module-random-has-no-attribute-randint)

Comment: Hola Joaquín, bienvenido. Una cosa, para futuras preguntas, es mejor que el título sea más directo, como "Error al leer excel con pandas en Python", o incluso nombrar el tipo de error o algo del error. Tu título actual tampoco es terrible, pero algo más directo y concreto puede ayudar a otros a encontrar tu pregunta antes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

El módulo que escribiste se llama `pandas.py`. Dentro de él haces

```
import pandas as np
```

Ahí está el conflicto: ¿de qué `pandas` hablas?

Solución: Renombra tu archivo `pandas.py`

Recomendación: Nunca uses palabras claves de Python o nombres de módulo para tus propias variables, funciones o módulos.